# How to set up multiple providers with different stores?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm currently working on project and I'm facing a problem. I'd love to end with different react sub-apps with different providers and store.

I've been already trying to apply two separate stores, without success so far. The main problem is when i have one global store everything is working just fine, when i try to apply different stores to different routes app is just simply using only first of them. Problem is that the app will be working on vulnerable data i have to split it among multiple stores.

Global store works just fine among component, but when i try to separate them it's not working properly.

So, this one is working good.

```
const MainTemplateWithRouter = (
<div>
   <Router>
       <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
              <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
                    <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
                    <Route path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
                    <Route path="/project-manager" component={ProjectManager} />
                    <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
                    <Route path="*"  component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
       </Provider>
   </Router>
</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(MainTemplateWithRouter, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Perfect solution would be something like that with one global store (to storing e.g. currently selected language (multi lang app)) and one store for each sub-app. As mentioned above. App will be huge with a lot of sub-apps that should be stored in different stores.

```
const MainTemplateWithRouter = (
<div>
   <Router>
           <h1>Header with Logo: XXXX</h1>
                <div>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        <br/><br/>
                </div>

       <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
              <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
                    <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
                    <Provider store={createStore(adminPanelReducers)}>
                    <Route path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
                    </Provider>
                    <Route path="/project-manager" component={ProjectManager} />
                    <Provider store={createStore(testReducer)}>
                    <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
                    </Provider>
                    <Route path="*"  component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
       </Provider>
   </Router>
</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(MainTemplateWithRouter, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve one global stores and separate stores for each subapp? If not, can i store currently selected lang in global context and create store for each sub-app?

@Edit

https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps was the thing i needed.

Separated the stores among sub-apps according to the docs. However i can't use global store and local stores at the same time.

Comment: This might help you out - https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps

Comment: Ohh yeah. That helped a lot.

Comment: @BaSic Did it? The article doesn't cover the part with common store. You can hardcode one of `connect` to specific store but I'm not sure that it's the best approach here.

Comment: @estus Helped with separating stores. Now i'm testing one global and sub-stores. If not then i'll try to use global context.

Comment: @estus Ye, Global store above sub-apps is not working inside sub apps. If i create global store, and sub store, only sub store can be accessed inside of the child component.

Comment: This won't work, you override parent Provider this way. I added an explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps) React Redux section addresses only multiple sibling stores.

React Redux 6 was changed to use React context API instead of legacy Context. Redux `Provider` uses React context `Provider` to provide a state to connected components. It's natural for context API `Provider` to override the value provided by parent `Provider`, so only innermost `Provider` will be taken into account by connected component.

If there are multiple nested stores, [they can have their own contexts](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#multiple-stores) that has to be specified in both Redux `Provider` and `connect`:

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext();
const AdminContext = React.createContext();

...

   <Provider context={GlobalContext} store={globalStore}>
     ...
     <Provider context={AdminContext} store={adminStore}>
        <Route path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
     </Provider>
      ...
   </Provider>

...

@connect(globalMapState, null, null, { context: GlobalContext })
@connect(adminMapState, null, null, { context: AdminContext })
class AdminPanel ...
```

Or sibling can use [default Redux context](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-reactreduxcontext-directly) to avoid boilerplate code:

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

...

   <Provider context={GlobalContext} store={globalStore}>
     ...
     <Provider store={adminStore}>
        <Route path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
     </Provider>
      ...
   </Provider>

...

@connect(globalMapState, null, null, { context: GlobalContext })
@connect(adminMapState)
class AdminPanel ...
```

Comment: This was very helpful - I had created a shared component library that needed to be wrapped in a `Provider` component, but I was getting invariant violation errors when trying to import that component into my larger app context, which was itself wrapped in a `Provider` component. By simply adding a `context` to the dependency, I was able to import it, no problem!