# How to migrate app to react-redux v6 and v7 with context API

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

From version 6, with React 16.3, react-redux add support for Context API.

```
// You can pass the context as an option to connect
export default connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch,
  null,
  { context: MyContext }
)(MyComponent)

// or, call connect as normal to start
const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(MyComponent)

// Later, pass the custom context as a prop to the connected component
;<ConnectedComponent context={MyContext} />
```

I'm migrating my app, but there are so many places need to add the `MyContext`, do we have some ways to safely add it for every `ConnectedComponent` in only one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a context explicitly to Redux `Provider` and `connect` is only needed if multiple nested stores have to be used, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55695651/3731501). This is a replacement for deprecated `store` option in `connect`.

If there multiple components that need to be connected with same custom context, helper HOC can be created:

```
const myConnect = (mapStateToProps = null, mapDispatchToProps = null, mergeProps = null, options = {}) => (
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps, {...options, context: MyContext })
);
```

If there's the only store or they don't intersect, custom context can be omitted, [default Redux context](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-reactreduxcontext-directly) will be used instead.

Comment: I use `connect(mapState, mapDispatch)`, and also the `reduxForm`, every place that I use them, do I have to pass `Context`?

Comment: If you use them with the same store, you don't need to pass a context.