# state received by mapStateToProps in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

When we connect Container component with Redux Store and write mapStateToProps in Container Component.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  //Access state here  
};
```

Does the state which mapStateToProps receives is complete Store state or some part of store state which only that Container component needed?

Does every Container Component receives Complete Store State?

Comment: You could simply try it. Though the question looks kinda strange how would infrastructure pick this "some part of store state"?

Comment: Brother i am new to Redux so i am confused that can we provide some specific state to Container component? or it receives complete state every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mapStateToProps is a method of react-redux library and it connects react components with redux store. when data is loaded root reducer combines state of all reducers and returns to mapStateToProps(state) object so yes mapStateToProps get complete redux store state.

Answer (score 1):

"**store**" you passed in store parameter in provider will be made availabe for your App Component and its child component.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

Since we passed whole store to our Provider,whole state is automatically passed to all child components of App Component.

To setup different provider with differet store,you can follow this

[How to set up multiple providers with different stores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684856/how-to-set-up-multiple-providers-with-different-stores)

Comment: Yes i know that but my question is does mapStateToProps in every Container component receives complete store state or we can provide some specific part of state which only that Container component needs?

Comment: can we provide specific state which only that Container component needs?

Comment: Since we passed whole store to our Provider.Whole state is automatically passed to all child components

Comment: If you want to provide specific state , you need to use multiple Provider

Answer (score 1):

Redux has a strong set of principles as **The store is the single source of truth**, So yes when you connect a component to the Redux store using `mapStateToProps`, you have access to the complete state object but it is you who decides what part of the state the component needs.

For example, you have an `inventory` reducer and a `cart` reducer in your store which both have an array of `items` as state value. In `mapStatetoProps` you have access to both the reducers' states, but you decide what your component needs. You can connect to `state.cart.items` or `state.inventory.items` or both if you want to.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // it is you who decides what your component need from the store in order to function
    // you can only select state.cart.items or state.inventory.items or both if you need
    cartItems: state.cart.items,
    inventoryItems: state.inventory.items 

});
```

Comment: For example Component1 is using state.cart.items and Component2 is using state.inventory.items so when state.cart.items changes by dispatching some action does both components Re-Renders?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. Suppose you have component1 connected to the store with `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` and component2 is a child of component1 so if the state changes and component1 receives new props it will rerender all of it's children. If you do not want to rerender a component unless it recieves new props you can use `React.memo` to memoize the component, but it will not work if you are using like `useContext` in side that component. Read more about `React.memo` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: Both are container components. Component1 is using state.cart.items and Component2 is using state.inventory.items. so when state.cart.items changes does both re-renders?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by container components. Are they both using `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` and connected to the store directly?

Comment: Yes both are connected with store. Presentational components are those which are dumb components that does not have any state. And Container Components are statefull components they are connected with Redux Store. Presentational Components are wrapped by Container components.

Comment: Presentational Components receive state from Container components through props

Comment: component2 should not rerender unless the state.inventory.items changes. But it it hard to say without at the exact implementation. If you want further optimization I recommend looking at using selectors instead. You can easily create selectors using the the [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a look at [redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit) as well, you may find it useful.